# use angularjs ui-router to implement a summary page

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

My web-app is written by AngularJs+ ui-router.

The web-app contains many forms (the number of forms are vary, depending on the application the user is applying). Each form has a ui-route state, so our users can go to each form and fill the information.

Before users submit the application we would like to implement a "summary/review" state(page) that contains all the forms the user filled, so users can review (and print) all the information from one page. Is there any way I can use  the same form template (templateUrl) for the summary page?

I was thinking to use ng-include and programmatically(ng-repeat) list out all the selected forms, but it seems doesn't work.

PS: my form template might use different controller..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I figured this out.

**For ng-include:** we need to use

`<ng-include src="'formPath'"></ng-include>`

**For putting the ng-include in a repeater:**

```
<div ng-repeat="f in vm.thisApp.RequiredForms">
    <ng-include src="f.FormPath"></ng-include>
</div>
```

I hope this helps anyone who needs the answer.